# For what $\lambda$ are the vectors linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem that needs to be solved is the following:

> For what $\lambda$'s are the vectors $u_1 = (\lambda + 1, \lambda, ... , \lambda), u_2 = (\lambda, \lambda + 1/2, ... , \lambda), ... , u_n = (\lambda, \lambda, ... , \lambda + 1/n)$ linearly dependent?

I'm trying to calculate the determinant using the set of vectors as columns, but I'm really struggling to simplify the determinant to a diagonal determinant that's easy to calculate. From there, I'm thinking we can set the determinant equal to 0 and then see what $\lambda$'s that satisfy the question above.

I also see that the determinant is symmetric along the diagonal, is there any nice trick that can be used for calculating the determinant in such instances?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$I_n(\lambda)=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda+1 &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda\\
\lambda &\lambda+\frac{1}{2} & \lambda &\cdots & \lambda\\
\lambda &\lambda & \lambda+\frac{1}{3}  &\cdots & \lambda\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
\lambda &\lambda & \lambda&\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
You can prove by induction, for example, that $det(I_n)=\dfrac{\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\lambda+1}{n!}$, for all $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 2}$.

Or maybe triangularizing is easier for you, in this case, we have (try to do the process for $n=3$ or $n=4$ and you will realize what is behind all that process.)
\begin{array}{cr}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda+1 &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda\\
\lambda &\lambda+\frac{1}{2} & \lambda &\cdots & \lambda\\
\lambda &\lambda & \lambda+\frac{1}{3}  &\cdots & \lambda\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
\lambda &\lambda & \lambda&\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}
\end{bmatrix}
&\xrightarrow[]{F_{1n}}\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\\
\lambda &\lambda+\frac{1}{2} & \lambda &\cdots & \lambda\\
\lambda &\lambda & \lambda+\frac{1}{3}  &\cdots & \lambda\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
\lambda+1 &\lambda & \lambda&\cdots &\lambda
\end{bmatrix}\\[3mm]
&\xrightarrow[2\leq k\leq n-1]{F_k-F_1} \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
\lambda+1 & \lambda & \lambda &\cdots & \lambda\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[3mm]
&\xrightarrow[]{F_n-(\frac{\lambda+1}{\lambda})F_1} \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
0 & -1 & -1 &\cdots & -\frac{(n+1)\lambda+1}{n\lambda}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[3mm]
&\xrightarrow[]{F_{2n}} \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & -1 & -1 &\cdots & -\frac{(n+1)\lambda+1}{n\lambda}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[3mm]
&\xrightarrow[]{F_n+\frac{1}{2}F_2} \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & -1 & -1 &\cdots & -\frac{(n+1)\lambda+1}{n\lambda}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} &\cdots & *\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[3mm]
&\xrightarrow[]{F_{3n}} \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & -1 & -1 &\cdots & -\frac{(n+1)\lambda+1}{n\lambda}\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} &\cdots & *\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} &\cdots & -\frac{1}{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[3mm]
&\vdots\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\color{white}{.}\\[3mm]
&\xrightarrow[]{} \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda &  \lambda& \lambda  &\cdots &\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\\
0 &-1 & -1 &\cdots & *\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} &\cdots & *\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots&\ddots &\vdots &\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & -\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\lambda+1}{(n-1)n \lambda}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{array}
Therefore $\beta=\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\}$ is linearly independent if $det(I_n)\neq 0$, that is, when $\lambda\neq \frac{-2}{n(n+1)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I don't really know how we can triangulize the determinant in the way you showed. Can you show the steps inbetween maybe?

Comment: @Tanamas I tried to do it step by step but you still to do case $n=4$ so that you fully understand it. Minimum I earned a reward +100, right? Haha

Comment: hahah you truly would deserve it. Thank you :)